# Admin-On-Rest add react-redux-toastr

Tags: toastr, admin-on-rest

i need to implement the extension "react-redux-toastr" into Admin-On-Rest.
how i can insert this code into the APP-Root

```
<ReduxToastr
      timeOut={4000}
      newestOnTop={false}
      preventDuplicates
      position="top-left"
      transitionIn="fadeIn"
      transitionOut="fadeOut"
      progressBar/>
```

This is not working

```
<Admin customReducers={{ watchlistAdd: researchReducer, toastr: toastrReducer  }} title="ProAmz" menu={Menu} restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://dell.does-it.net:3306/api/v1')}>
        <Resource  name="amazon_products" title="Produkte" list={ProductList}/>
        <Resource  name="Watchlist" title="Watchlist" list={Watchlist} />
        <div>

        <ReduxToastr
      timeOut={4000}
      newestOnTop={false}
      preventDuplicates
      position="top-left"
      transitionIn="fadeIn"
      transitionOut="fadeOut"
      progressBar/>

        </div>


    </Admin>
```

i won't use the "custom-app" https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html version.